# Is there a way to limit max credit number or coins inserted on mame?

Tags: emulation, mame

I'm using [RetroPie](https://retropie.org.uk/) as my retro videogame at home(using [Recalbox](https://www.recalbox.com/) as for today, but I still have a sdcard with RetroPie for thinkering). Default emulator is [`lr-mame2003`](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/MAME#lr-mame2003-mame-2003) and it is pretty well integrated with EmulationStation(the graphical frontend).

What I want to know is, and I found no tips at the documentation: **Is there a way to create a credit limit per game reset to somehow "emulate" inside mame the continue behavior of cartidge games?** I want to limit Sunset Riders to 3 credits per game reset for example.

Someone could ask "why not play the Snes/Genesis version of this game then?". Well, that is because we are doing a party with old friends from my childhood, and it will be more fun to play 4 players arcade version than just the 2 player video game version. And it will not be that fun if putting credits is an unlimited action.

Comment: Why the tag `libretro` got removed? isn't this tag relevant?

Comment: The tag is completely irrelevant, as it has nothing to do with playing games.  That's why I removed it.  [It's a development API](https://www.libretro.com/), which developers need, but isn't needed when our focus is on how to play games, not make them.

Comment: Yes it is relevant. Some of the configuration is done through `libretro` and the rest is done by command line passing arguments to the "core"(emulator) itself, or by editing the emulation config file. This will make people know that technology im using during emulation, and give better anwers. @DanmakuGrazer - I've made an edit to that tag, but i'm waiting it to be peer reviewed - It's some sort of "emulation centralizer" in a very simplistic way https://www.libretro.com/index.php/api/

Comment: If i post that on Raspberry, Unix & Linux and StackExchange will be off-topic as well. Here, it seems to be LESS offtopic than at the other communities. I'm not asking to this functionality be CODED.. Just asking if this feature exists on this kind of emulation, and how can i achieve it...

Comment: That part is fine.  The point is the tag is useless; we're never going to have questions about it, because our focus is on playing games.  How it's handled doesn't matter to us; we're never going to be experts in a development API.  Generally, you *can* create a tag, but that doesn't automatically mean you *should*.  If you're asking *how* to use the API, that's totally off-topic for us.  We don't do development here, except for the in-game stuff like Minecraft.

Comment: Ok. Remove the tag if you will. But i still think it's as relevant as `dolphin-emulator` for example(if you really "don't care hot it's handled"), and libretro is not ONLY an API if you look at the broad scenario where is integrated with retroarch(and i have put that info on my tag edit). I'm just adding info on how i am emulatin: Not inside windows, not directly through a binary/emulator executable, but through [libretro+retroarch configurations](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/blob/master/retroarch.cfg)...

Comment: Isn't the number of coins going to be dependent on the game rather than the emulator?

Comment: Well, that is something i dont care, if it's implemented at the emulator, ROM, script or memory injection :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And it will not be that fun if putting credits is an unlimited action.

I had the same problem with my RetroPie cabinet. To solve this I devised a joystick system with an integrated credit counter. The system disables the insert coin buttons unless credits are available and includes a little challenge that must be won in order to obtain them. The challenge is the Simon Says electronic game created by Ralph Baer and Howard J. Morrison in 1978. As in the original Simon game there are several skill levels. The number of credits obtained when the game is won will depend on the selected skill level. You can see the project at [hackster.io](https://www.hackster.io/user3853574654/arcade-joystick-x4-plus-simon-game-384309) and [github.com](https://github.com/gambaman/ArcadeJoystickX4PlusSimonGame). You can also see a video demo at [youtu.be](https://youtu.be/ENW7n0ni5kg).
[image]

Comment: You sir, are a true hacker! Reading this answer made my day happier. Will I implement it? Maybe not, cause i'm using a simple RPI3 in a case paired with PS3 bluetooth controlers. But your solution is some of those who deserve the spotlights. I'll create a bounty and give it to you, marking your answer as the valid one.

Answer (score 3):

No such feature exists, though I guess a skilled programmer could add something like that to the MAME source code. Since the purpose of MAME is to preserve the games in their original state, I doubt such a feature will ever be added to the official MAME release.

Comment: Using `mame` you can increase the Credit rate per coin so, i thought someone could have implemented the "coin cap" or "credit cap" on the emulator...

Comment: As far as I know, that's a feature of the individual game, and not so much a feature of MAME. If it was available in the original Arcade machine, it's generally available in MAME as well.